Covering Map Associated to Map from Homology
Let $X_n$ be a connected $2$-dimensional manifold with nonempty boundary and set $X_n^*:=X_n-\{x_0\}$. Assume that $H^1(X^*_n;\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb{R}$. Then since
$$H^1(X_n^*;\mathbb{R}) = \text{Hom}(H_1(X^*_n;\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{R})$$
and $H_1(X^*_n;\mathbb{Z})$ is a finitely generated abelian group, there is a surjective homomorphism $H_1(X^*_n;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ whose kernel is finite.
The source I'm reading then argues that there is a corresponding covering map $p\colon \widetilde{X^*_n}\rightarrow X^*_n$ where the group of covering transformations is infinite cyclic and generated by an element $\alpha$ obtained by lifting a loop around $x_0$.
My questions is: where does the map $p$ come from? The Galois correspondence for covering spaces is between covering maps and subgroups of the fundamental group, not the first homology. I know the Hurewicz map relates the abelianization of $\pi_1(X^*_n)$ with $H_1(X_n^*)$, but I've tried to work out the details and haven't been able to, as even for the most basic surfaces $\pi_1$ is not $H_1$.

Does $x_0$ lie in the interior of $X_n$?

@Sumanta Yes it does.

@Vasting Is there a problem with taking the cover classifying the kernel of $\pi_1(X_n^) \to H_1(X_n^) \to \mathbb{Z}$?

Your $X_n$ is contractible and $\pi_1(X_n^*)=\mathbb Z$.
